# Exceptions on threadpool threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

Related:

- [How to catch exceptions from a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841)
- [Exceptions on .Net ThreadPool Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668265/exceptions-on-net-threadpool-threads)

---

If a method throws an exceptions that is called by the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method where will the exception be thrown? or will it just be eaten?

I mean it will never be thrown on the calling thread right?

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch exceptions from a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, the exception will never propagate to another thread. It will eventually crash the thread, and be caught by the runtime. At this point the runtime raises the AppDomain.UnhandledException event where the exception can be observed.

You can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: which also ends up crashing the app

Answer (score 4):

The exception will crash your application if is not caught inside your thread callback (except for ThreadAbortException and AppDomainUnloadedException that are swallowed).  Note that in .NET 1.1 all exceptions were swallowed.  The behavior was changed in .NET 2.0.

I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Unhandled exceptions will bring down the app in .Net 2.0 or higher.  The exception from QUWI code will not be caught or transferred to another thread.

See e.g. 
https://blog.codinghorror.com/improved-unhandled-exception-behavior-in-net-20/