# Why is Visual Studio skipping over my Exception from a ThreadPool work item?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, exception, threadpool

I am aware of this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem), but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

First off, here is my environment:
Windows XP 64-bit SP3; Visual Studio 2008 w/ SP; .NET 3.5 SP1;  WPF application.

My problem is that I cannot seem to step to where my exception happens.  It just keeps running instead of continuing the debugging session.

Here is some code -- I didn't write all of it, so please, no need for comments on naming :)

```
// start up the WPF application
// set the handler for the Checked event
ToggleButton channelButton1 = new ToggleButton();
channelButton1.Checked += (s, e) => 
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SetTcpChannel, 1);
```

Then in that `SetTcpChannel` method:

```
    try
    {
        int channel = (int)state;
        EnsureTcpSocket();
        // more logic to do stuff with channel 
        // that we don't care about for SO
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // just for illustration
        // this is where I expected the code to return
        ...
    }
```

And finally, in the place where the exception actually happens (inside `EnsureTcpSocket`):

```
    if (_tcp == null)
    {
        // this is not a valid ip/port since the 
        // target machine is not running (test condition)
        // but that's ok, I should get some exception 
        // and continue debugging...right?
        _tcp = new TcpClient(ip, port);
    }
```

Here is what I have been doing:

1. I set a breakpoint at the
   `EnsureTcpSocket` line inside
   `SetTcpChannel`,
2. F11 (step-into) `EnsureTcpSocket` 
   so I can see the `_tcp` piece of
   code
3. Try to F10 (step-over) the
   `TcpClient` constructor

At that last step, the application comes back up from the debugger and keeps running and I never see any exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long did you wait? Depending on exactly what the arguments are, the `TcpClient` constructor may wait until it times out before throwing the exception. (If the connection is refused, that's a different matter.)

Comment: Doh!  I had waited for a little, but obviously forgot to wait for the TCP timeout period.  I had kept closing it down before it got around to throwing the actual exception.

Comment: Gosh - I hardly expected that to actually be the reason. I thought it was worth mentioning just in case :)

Comment: Honestly, I feel like I should shed some rep for that.  SO should have a "flagellate yourself" option when you realize that you did something very dumb.

Comment: Psychic debugging at it's best :)

Comment: @Erich: None of us would have any rep left.

Comment: @Erich Mirabal, we all probably spend too much time on the "very dumb" errors. If we didn't have the "dumb errors" to account for, then task estimation would actually be a useful practice. Don't sweat it, that's what the community is all about. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a breakpoint inside the catch block, if not I don't see why the debugger would break the execution and stop there?

Alternatively, in Visual Studio you can set debugging options to break on First Chance exceptions, here's [an old post that describes how](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/18/440150.aspx).

Comment: That wasn't my problem, but thanks for providing some other very useful links.