# C# ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

Whenever a thread in my ThreadPool throws an exception, my code seems to be stuck at the catch block inside the thread function. How do I get the exception back to the main thread?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch exceptions from a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem)

Comment: those methods dont work. I get an exception saying `The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this. `

Comment: Ok, it might be worth posting some code. This sounds like you're possibly accessing a GUI component from a non-GUI thread.

Comment: I am accessing a listbox to add the exception from the thread. If I throw directly its stuck in the thread catch block, it wont go back to the main thread

Comment: If you're directly accessing a ListBox from a ThreadPool thread and the ListBox was created on a different thread, you'll need to use the Control.Invoke to ensure you only access the ListBox from the Gui thread which created it.

Comment: could you show me some sample code? How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to show what you're trying to do. Then I'll update my answer with some code if required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch exceptions from a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice is that your background threads should not throw exceptions. Let them handle their exceptions on their own.

Ideally you should wrap the code in your method that executes on a thread in a try-catch block and handle the exception in the catch block. Do not re-throw it from the catch block.

Read this for more details. http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Exception_Handling

If you want to update the UI from background thread you can do that by using [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) property and [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method. See the MSDN links for details and examples.

Comment: But my UI has to display the exception. What can I do?

Comment: Catch it in the thread and use a queue (pipe) to send a message back to the UI thread to display the error. Exceptions over thread borders is a bad thing and very hard to trouble shot.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to transfer exception from a thread to another one. What can you do is to built some synchronization mechanism to transfer exception information between threads and then throw a new exception from the target thread something like:

```
class Program
{
    Exception _savedException = null;
    AutoResetEvent _exceptionEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.RunMain();
    }

    void RunMain()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadMethod));

        while (true)
        {
            _exceptionEvent.WaitOne();
            if (_savedException != null)
            {
                throw _savedException;
            }
        }
    }

    void ThreadMethod(object contxt)
    {
        try
        {
            // do something that can throw an exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _savedException = ex;
            _exceptionEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a Win form application things are much simpler. In the catch clause of your thread use Invoke (or BeginInvoke) method of your form, providing it with the exception details. In the method launched with Invoke you can rethrow or treat your exception as you want.