# WPF - Catch exceptions in code executed by SimpleMVVM messagebus

Tags: wpf, exception, simple-mvvm

I'm building a WPF application using the [SimpleMVVM framework](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/) and I'm having trouble catching exceptions. I use the MessageBus of SimpleMVVM to send a message to another viewmodel. This all works fine, but I noticed that exceptions raised in the code executed by the messagebus get suppressed. Here's what I've got so far:

My `MainWindow` contains a button that fires a `TempCommand` on the MainWindowViewModel. This command in turn calls the `Test` method (shown below), which sends out a notification message using the MessageBus of SimpleMVVM.

```
private void Temp()
{
    SendMessage("Temp", new NotificationEventArgs());
}
```

My `MainWindow` also contains a `Frame` with content. The ViewModel of this content, `CustomerViewModel`, has registered to receive these notifications in its constructor:

```
public CustomerDetailsViewModel(ICustomerServiceAgent agent)
{
    RegisterToReceiveMessages("Temp", Temp);
}
```

Where the `Temp` method simply throws an exception:

```
private void Temp(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("Somewhere, something horrible happened");
}
```

When I debug the application, I clearly see the `Temp` method being called and the exception being raised. But for some reason, that's all. The application is unaffected and my exception trapping code is unaware of the exception.

I trap exceptions in two ways. The first is by handling the event on the `Dispatcher`:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException">
```

Where the code-behind looks like:

```
private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Log("Exception: " + e.Exception.Message);
    e.Handled = true;
}
public static void Log(string message)
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\Temp\log.txt", "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("F") + "] [" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "] " + message + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

This code catches some exceptions, but not all. I found out that WPF suppresses databinding exceptions by default. Because my ViewModels are bounded through the `DataContext` property on my view, I thought this was the problem. I found [this article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors), which defines a `TraceListener` that uses the `PresentationTraceSources` class. Databinding exceptions now get caught, but... Not the exceptions thrown in the code executed through the MessageBus.

I've created a solution demonstrating this behavior, it can be downloaded [here](http://sdrv.ms/11xXVPe).

And this is where I'm stuck. What am I missing? How do I catch these exceptions?

Big thanks in advance.

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug or problem with the implementation of the [MessageBus](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23821#313594) in SimpleMVVM.

Cause multiple subscribers can subscribe to a token, the current implementation ensures that each subscribed method gets called even when one registered method throws an exception. In this case the exception is catched and written out to the Console.

The method that is responsible to call a subscribed method is SafeNotify

```
private void SafeNotify(Action method, bool post) {
  try {
    // Fire the event on the UI thread
    if (post){
      if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess()){
        method();
      }
      else{
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method);
      }
    }
    // Fire event on a ThreadPool thread
    else{
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => method(), null);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
    // If there's an exception write it to the Output window
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

When the method call gets queued in the ThreadPool, you have no chance to handle the thrown exception. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753841/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem) for further information.

The only option you have is to ensure that the code of your own registered methods is always surrounded by a try-catch-block.

Comment: That's definitely a bug in the SimpleMVVM message bus. It should broadcast the message to all clients, but still bubble up any exceptions, possibly via an AggregateException.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose the best I can do is catch as many exceptions as I can and be extra cautious with functions called by the MessageBus. Also, is my Reflector the only one that keeps crashing when inspecting the `InternalNotify` function? Thanks again.