# Why an exception in ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem action does not crash an application when it should?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, threadpool

I have a problem. An exception in the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` does not crash an application, but I want it to crash it and I know normally it does. There is a difference in my case. My `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is wrapped up into an awaiter like this

```
public struct YieldThreadPoolAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (continuation == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(continuation));
        }
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunAction, continuation);
    }

    public void GetResult() { }

    private static void RunAction(object state)
    {
        ((Action)state)();
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

To me, it looks the same as just calling `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` but here it is called indirectly when I do:

```
await ThreadPoolEx.Yield();
```

I see that the execution goes inside `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, I know an exception is thrown there but the exception is somehow quietly swallowed, and the application does not crash.

The question is - WHY? What special .NET Framework is doing that the application does not crash in this case and how to change back this behavior and make it crash?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/753841/1132334

Comment: Show more code - like the `ThreadPoolEx.Yield` implementation and where the exception is being thrown

Comment: What version and flavor of .net are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I call the `OnCompleted` with an action that throws, and I get un unhandled exception as expected. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s0WxRN) is my attempt for a repro.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are calling `await ThreadPoolEx.Yield();` from within an `async Task` method, like [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2PFPAx).

In that case, the continuation passed to `OnCompleted` is not just your code; it's the appropriate part of the code generated by the `async` state machine. And if that code is in an `async Task` method, then part of that generated state machine code deliberately catches exceptions and places them on the returned task.

To summarize: behavior is as expected. If you want an exception within an `async` method to crash the app, use `async void` instead of `async Task`.